# Why does SQL Server 2008 crashed on simple SQL queries?

Tags: sql-server, msdtc

I'm a developer and running a SQL Server 2008 SP1 instance (default instance) on my local machine (Windows 7 RC 32-Bit).
Sometimes when the program I'm developing sends a query to the SQL Server, the whole SQL Server crashes. The SQL queries are not complex, just simple CRUD queries. When I restart the server, the next query kills him again.

The event log entry states that an error happens because of MS DTC. Unfortunately I don't have any idea why. When I'm using the SQL Server for other purposes through SQL Server Management Studio, I haven't encountered any problems, so I don't think it has to do with my operation system.

Does anybody have ideas why SQL Server crashes? It makes development really difficult, sometimes even impossible.

Best Regards,
Oliver Hanappi

PS: Here is the event log entry.

> An MS DTC component has generated an exception. Error Specifics: The process '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe" -sMSSQLSERVER' hit an exception in a MSDTC related component.
>   The following exception (0xc0000005) was generated at 0x        00FEAC8C, Pid:7400.
>   The process is being terminated.
>   Additional information useful in a debugger:
>   You can do '.exr 0x0369E930' to display the exception record.
>   You can do '.cxr 0x0369E94C' to display the context at the time of the exception.
>
> 0

Answer (score 1):

You must be running distributed transactions from your software to the database.  Do you need to run explicit distributed transactions?

DTC is a part of the OS, not the SQL Server.  You are probably running against a bug in MSDTC which is in the RC version of Windows 7.

If you don't need explicit distributed transactions then disable the use of transactions within your code.  If you do need to use the explicit distributed transactions then try running your code on a release version of the OS, instead of a pre-release OS.

Answer (score 1):

RC = release candidate = NOT PRODUCTION READY

I would not use Windows 7 until other people have bled the way and figured out all the issues...

Comment: If possible, get the RTM versions via MSDN if it's so important...